# How to change logo of my add-in/taskpane on the menu bar

Tags: office-js

I have built my Excel add-in/taskpane using the [template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator) of Microsoft. Everything works fine. However I am trying to change the default logo of the sample add-in and replace the name "Contoso" with my add-in name (in pictures)

[image]
[image]

I have removed all original images that came with the sample add-in template, delete all text containing the word "Contoso" and "Show Taskpane", however the logo, the word Contoso and the phrase "Show Taskpane" are still there. Really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I test/sideload my add-in everything works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac

Answer (score 0):

Add-ins are often cached in Office for Mac, for performance reasons. Normally, the cache is cleared by reloading the add-in.

You can clear the cache by using the personality menu of any task pane add-in.

- Choose the personality menu. Then choose Clear Web Cache.
- You can also clear the cache manually by deleting the contents of the `~/Library/Containers/com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost/Data/` folder. If that folder doesn't exist, check for the following folders and if found, delete the contents of the folder:
- ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.{host}/Data/Library/Caches/ where {host} is the Office application (e.g., Excel)
- ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.{host}/Data/Library/Application
- Support/Microsoft/Office/16.0/Wef/ where {host} is the Office application (e.g., Excel)
- ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/Data/Caches/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/
- ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/Data/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/

Answer (score 0):

Also try upgrading the version `<Version></Version>` in your manifest. Especially when deploying your manifest, this may fix cache issues